# Change The Volume in System.Media.SoundPlayer

Tags: c#

I am using System.Media.SoundPlayer to play some wav files in my project.
Is it possible to change the volume of this SoundPlayer?  If there is no way to do that, how can I change the volume of my computer using C#?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521363/soundplayer-adjustable-volume/50521912#50521912).

Answer (score 3):

From [SoundPlayer adjustable volume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50521912/719186):

---

Unfortunately [`SoundPlayer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't provide an API for changing the volume. You could use the [`MediaPlayer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
using System.Windows.Media;

public class Sound
{
    private MediaPlayer m_mediaPlayer;

    public void Play(string filename)
    {
        m_mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        m_mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(filename));
        m_mediaPlayer.Play();
    }

    // `volume` is assumed to be between 0 and 100.
    public void SetVolume(int volume)
    {
        // MediaPlayer volume is a float value between 0 and 1.
        m_mediaPlayer.Volume = volume / 100.0f;
    }
}
```

You'll also need to add references to the `PresentationCore` and `WindowsBase` assemblies.