# SoundPlayer adjustable volume

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class `Sounds.cs` that manages playing sounds in my form, and I want to be able to adjust the volume to decimal value. Is there a way to change the volume of a sound being played with a `SoundPlayer` object? Or is there perhaps a different way to play sound that makes this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "adjust the volume to decimal value" ? Please add the code you tried.

Comment: @AsthaSrivastava I haven't tried any code because I don't know where to start. I have a variable `volume` that is somewhere between 0 and 100, and I want to be able to adjust the volume of the sound played with `player.Play()`.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately [`SoundPlayer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't provide an API for changing the volume. You could use the [`MediaPlayer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
using System.Windows.Media;

public class Sound
{
    private MediaPlayer m_mediaPlayer;

    public void Play(string filename)
    {
        m_mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        m_mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(filename));
        m_mediaPlayer.Play();
    }

    // `volume` is assumed to be between 0 and 100.
    public void SetVolume(int volume)
    {
        // MediaPlayer volume is a float value between 0 and 1.
        m_mediaPlayer.Volume = volume / 100.0f;
    }
}
```

You'll also need to add references to the `PresentationCore` and `WindowsBase` assemblies.

Comment: Just what I'm looking for! How would I get the Uri of a .wav file if its an embedded resource? Would it be best to not embed them, and just use a file path?

Comment: Ah yeah , `MediaPlayer` doesn't support that. You'll have to just put the .wav file somewhere on disk.

Comment: MediaPlayer appeared to work, but came with the side effect of making my windows form half its size for some odd reason.

Comment: Woah that is super weird! Are you using WinForms? `PresentationCore` is part of WPF; maybe there is some incompatibility.

Comment: I had trouble finding `System.Windows.Media`. Search for `PresentationCore` in the "Add Reference..." Window of Visual Studio. You will also need the reference `WindowBase` for the `Open()` and `Play()` functions of MediaPlayer class.